# VBA - Ranking Highest to Lowest by Counting Negative Values?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

How to rank highest to lowest by counting negative values?

[image]

I would probably use something like this follow by if elseif logic but I can't seems to figure it out

```
Set CountRng = range("B1:E1") 
CountApple = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CountRng, "<0")
CountOrange ..
CountBanana ..

If CountApple > CountOrange then or endif...
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: so 1st place would have the least or the most cells under 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(OFFSET($B$1,(ROW($1:$3)-1),0,1,4),"<0")>COUNTIF(B1:E1,"<0")))+1
```

[image]

Comment: You tagged it with formula.