# Counting Negative Values and Ranking Them

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to count the negative values and rank them from highest count to lowest

```
Banana  -1   2  -3   2   1
Orange   4  -3  -3  -1   2
Apple    1  -4   1   1   2
```

I was going to use the worksheet function like this

```
Set CountRng = range("B1:F1") 
CountBanana = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CountRng, "<0")
```

But not sure how I can rank them. Maybe I need to use array here?

Result should rank Orange (3), Banana (2) and Apple (1)
Output in cell G1:G3

Comment: What's the logic behind the ranking? How is Orange 3 and Apple 1?

Comment: By counting the negative values, orange has -3, -3, -1 so 3 Apple has -4 so 1

Comment: I followed all posting rules and tagged them correctly but why people down arrowing my post? This is very valid question that you can't Google or digging through the previous posts...

Comment: And this ranking, is it a reordering of the cells, or just another column with the rank?

Comment: Do you need VBA? This can be done with a simple formula

Comment: Yes VBA only. I know this is very simple with formula but unfortunately that's not an option :(

Comment: Please see my last question. Also you can record a macro. If you answer the last question, I can work up an answer

Comment: Orange is 3 because there are 3 negative values (-3, -3 and -1) in that row Apple is 1 because there is 1 negative value (-4)

Comment: I'm curious why a formula is not allowed, but you can use VBA for some reason?

Comment: Generally, Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please show more than two lines of code.  Show how you have attempted to do what you are asking.  You basically are asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: @TylerH, I already tried, this is the second time the OP has asked this question([first now deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350988/vba-ranking-highest-to-lowest-by-counting-negative-values/56351106#56351106)).  He tagged it with excel-formula last time and I gave him a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Evaluate with the formula I gave the first time you asked:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet3") 'change to your worksheet
    Dim lstRow As Long
    lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lstRow
        .Cells(i, 7).Value = .Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(OFFSET($B$1,(ROW($1:$" & lstRow & ")-1),0,1,5),""<0"")<COUNTIF(B" & i & ":F" & i & ",""<0"")))+1")
    Next i
End With
```

[image]